# how to make only one flex item strech while other restricted to keep their natural height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want all of the flex items except last to just occupy their normal height and the last flex-item to occupy remaining height of the flexbox (stretch). But I have not been able to do that.

Following is what I have been trying:

```css
  .parent {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        /*align-content: start;*/
        border: 1px solid green;
        height: 50vh
    }

    .child-height-auto {
        align-self: start;
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .child-height-strech {
        align-self: stretch;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-height-auto">I should occupy my normal height</div>
    <div class="child-height-auto">I should occupy my normal height</div>
    <div class="child-height-strech">I should occupy remaining height of the flexbox</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't you mean `width` instead of `height` ?

Comment: No I mean height. width is 100% anyway

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the direction of the flex to `column` and add flex-grow property to the last element.

```css
  .parent {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        /*align-content: start;*/
        border: 1px solid green;
        height: 50vh;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .child-height-auto {
        align-self: start;
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .child-height-strech {
        align-self: stretch;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        width: 100%;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-height-auto">I should occupy my normal height</div>
    <div class="child-height-auto">I should occupy my normal height</div>
    <div class="child-height-strech">I should occupy remaining height of the flexbox</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Its a good thinking. But can it be done while keeping flex-direction = row?

Comment: No, according to the spec, what you want requires a flex container into another flex container, each with different directions. The above answer is the correct.

Comment: @i_read_terms_and_services Artur's answer was great, so I made a little improvement so you don't have to name all your children (specifically the last one) a different class. Hope it heps! [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/wauLkbxp/37/)

Comment: Unnecessary CSS here. All you need is `flex-grow: 1` on the last item and `flex-direction: column` on the container.

Answer (score 4):

First, you should add `flex-direction: column;` and remove `flex-wrap`. Then you can assign different `flex-grow` parameters to your classes for the flex items (the last one may grow, the others not) - see below.

```css
.parent {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        border: 1px solid green;
        height: 50vh
    }

    .child-height-auto {
        align-self: start;
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 100%;
        flex-grow: 0;
    }

    .child-height-strech {
        align-self: stretch;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        width: 100%;
        flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-height-auto">I should occupy my normal height</div>
    <div class="child-height-auto">I should occupy my normal height</div>
    <div class="child-height-strech">I should occupy remaining height of the flexbox</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Notice how you can delete `.child-height-auto` CSS alltogether and get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

**Try following code**

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 50vh;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.child-height-auto {
  align-self: start;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
.child-height-strech {
  align-self: stretch;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-height-auto">I should occupy my normal height</div>
    <div class="child-height-auto">I should occupy my normal height</div>
    <div class="child-height-strech">I should occupy remaining height of the flexbox</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having issues, check these two things:

- Don't forget to set `flex-direction` on your parent
- Don't forget to set `align-self: stretch;` on the child you want to stretch

Answer (score 0):

Apply CSS `flex-direction: column` to the flexbox container and `flex-grow: 1` on the last item.

Here's an interactive flexbox demo to help craft CSS: https://ronnieroyston.com/tools/css-flexbox

Here's a working example:

```css
main {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100px;
 outline: dotted;
}

#item-three {
 flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<main id=container>
  <div id=item-one>item-one</div>
  <div id=item-two>item-two</div>
  <div id=item-three>item-three</div>
</main>
```